# Spring boot starter parent pom

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

With maven, Spring boot requires to inherit it's starter POM as a parent, rendering you unable to inherit from custom POM.

Now the problem is, in the custom POM I have defined properties, profiles, build functionality and dependencies that are common for all the modules of that project. How do I use Spring boot without duplicating the configuration in all the modules that uses Spring boot?

One solution would inherit the custom parent POM from Spring boot starter POM, but this would intrude Spring to inappropriate modules.

Is there a simple solution for this dilemma?